# Capture sheet name for a copy range

Tags: excel, vba

I have written vba to combine 50 sheets to one master sheet. It works. Now though they need to know what sheet the entry came from for correction purposes. How would I capture the sheet name?

```
For Each sh In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets 

If sh.Name <> DestSh.Name 
Then Last = Range("A100000").End(xlUp).Row 
Set CopyRng = sh.Range("A2:k2" & Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row) 
If Last + CopyRng.Rows.Count > DestSh.Rows.Count Then 
MsgBox "There are not enough rows in the " & _ 
           "summary worksheet to place the data." 
GoTo ExitTheSub 
End If 

CopyRng.Copy 

With DestSh.Cells(Last + 1, "A") 
.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, skipBlanks:=True 
Application.CutCopyMode = False 
End With 

(CopyRng.Rows.Count).Value = sh.Name 

End If 

Next
```

Comment: Posting some code would help a lot.

Comment: Problem is that i can't post to your site from work so i am having to use cell phone. Just need to tell it yo capture the sheet name and save it to column L if that makes sense.

Comment: Without knowing more I would say the simplest way would be to just add a column at the right potentially titled "Source Sheet" perhaps, and just populate it in all the entries.  Then edit the VBA to grab it as well.  Simple but it should work...with the added benefit of being able to sort on the sheet...should that be useful.

Comment: I am trying to login from desk so I can copy code but it won't let me use yahoo to login.. Give me a few pleas

Comment: For Each sh In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
If sh.Name <> DestSh.Name Then
Last = Range("A100000").End(xlUp).Row
Set CopyRng = sh.Range("A2:k2" & Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)
If Last + CopyRng.Rows.Count > DestSh.Rows.Count Then
MsgBox "There are not enough rows in the " & _
"summary worksheet to place the data."
GoTo ExitTheSub
End If
CopyRng.Copy
With DestSh.Cells(Last + 1, "A")
.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, skipBlanks:=True
Application.CutCopyMode = False
End With
(CopyRng.Rows.Count).Value = sh.Name
End If
Next

Comment: Tim, It only captures 1 sheet name and it is the last sheet.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a **Range** and want to know the **Sheet** associated with that **Range** :

```
Public Function WhichSheet(r As Range) As String
    WhichSheet = ""
    If Not r Is Nothing Then
        WhichSheet = r.Parent.Name
    End If
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

This was the answer that did it...

```
CopyRng.Copy

With DestSh.Cells(Last + 1, "A")
.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, skipBlanks:=True
Application.CutCopyMode = False
End With

DestSh.Cells(Last + 1, "Q").Resize(CopyRng.Rows.Count).Value = sh.Name
```

Thanks for the help guys.